# Make current HTML row editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

[image]

In the screenshot, I want to be able to use the onClick event of the edit image to make the 5 proceeding text boxes of the same row editable.  By default I have set them 'readonly'.  I have looked for other solutions but I am not sure how to reference the current row.

```
<table class = "idtable" cellspacing="0">                                                
    <tr style="background-color:#999999;color:white">
      <th width="200px" class="tablehead">Type</th>
      <th width="200px" class="tablehead">Value</th>
      <th width="200px" class="tablehead">State</th>
      <th width="200px" class="tablehead">Status</th>
      <th width="200px" class="tablehead">Entry Date</th>
      <th width="100px" class="tablehead">Edit</th>
      <th width="100px" class="tablehead">Delete</th>
    </tr>   

    <tr style="text-align:center">
      <td class="idtable-borderleft"><input id="idType" class="readonly" type="text" value="INSTSERVICES" readonly></td>
      <td class="idtable-bordermid"><input id="idValue" class="readonly" type="text" value="1234        " readonly></td>
      <td class="idtable-bordermid"><input id="idState" style="font-size:85%" class="readonly" type="text"  value="UNMODIFIED" readonly></td>
      <td class="idtable-bordermid"><input id="idStatus" class="readonly" type="text" value="Active" readonly></td>
      <td class="idtable-bordermid"><input id="idStartDate" class="readonly" type="text" value="2015-03-17" readonly></td>
      <td class="idtable-bordermid"><img onclick="editRow()" src="https://localhost:8443/xxxxx/images/edit.png"></td>
      <td class="idtable-borderright"><a href="/xxxxx/timeServ.do?formName=updateIDs&delete=true&assocID=5320&credID=1234" ><img src="xxxxx/images/delete.gif"></a></td>
    </tr>                                                   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7"><input style="margin-left:50%; margin-top: 5px" type="submit" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>                                                   
</table>
```

Comment: We need the structure of this table. Could you please post relevant HTML for us?

Comment: What other solutions? Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Start a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a sample of your code and it'll be easier to help out.

Comment: I meant that I have looked at other solutions but they weren't really what I was looking for.

Comment: since you're already using jquery, you can tryJQGrid.

Comment: How would I use JQGrid to allow edits?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `onClick` tag.

Attach to the click event using jQuery, then traverse the DOM to find the row and finally manipulate the `input` tags.

In this example, I assume that you added a class of `btnedit` to the image:

```
$('.idtable .btnedit').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); //find the parent row
    var inputs = $('input', row); //find all the inputs inside the row
    inputs.prop('readonly', false); //change the attribute
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o26q8w6j/

Answer (score -1):

You need to use something like jQuery editable.

Try double clicking text in below demo

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

You need to fire ajax call to update data in database.